# Search a string in a file in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I must search a string in a file, and i assert a fact if the term is present.

For example

My file:

```
  title"Fast and furious"
  year"2013"
  actor"Vin Diesel"

assert(title(Fast and furious)),
assert(year(2013)),
assert(actor(Vin Diesel)).
```

How can I do?

EDIT:

Is it possibile extract a part of a string?

```
<title>Fast and Furious</title>
```

I would get only "Fast and Furious" and then i would assert(title(Fast and Furious)). Is it possibile? I don't use library(sgml) of swi_prolog.

Comment: I'm confused. Does the file have the assert clauses or just the raw data?

Comment: The file has only the raw data. My system should have the assert clauses.

Comment: It is still not clear what you mean by "search": do you need to only pick out certain terms, or one particular term, or all terms in the file? Do you need to validate your input or is it well-formed? Do you need to do it in Prolog, or can you use sed/awk for generating the Prolog code?

Comment: I have a file in input, an html file. I don't use library(sgml) of swi-prolog but i must create my module. I search some tags in html file. For example <title>Prove</title>, <div></div>.... Is there a way to search in a file the term <title>...</title> and then i get in output "Prove"? I would extract part of a string.

Answer (score 2):

In SWI-Prolog the easy way is using [phrase_from_file](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc_for?object=section%283,%27A.19.1%27,swi%28%27/doc/Manual/pio.html%27%29%29):

```
file --> "title", dquo(Title), "\nyear", dquo(Year), "\nactor", dquo(Actor),
   {assert(title(Title)), assert(year(Year)), assert(actor(Actor))}.

dquo(A) --> "\"", any(S), "\"", {atom_codes(A, S)}.

any([]) --> [].
any([C|Cs]) --> [C], any(Cs).
```

*edit*: DCG are plain, declarative Prolog: to use different delimiters than double quotes, try

```
title(T) --> "<title>", any(S), "</title>", {atom_codes(T, S)}.
```

I hope you will appreciate the flexibility of DCG rules. SWI-Prolog has an helper [library](http://www.swi-prolog.org/pldoc/doc/swi/library/dcg/basics.pl) with some handy predefined rule.